# Harnack's Inequality and (hypo)elliptic PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Background: I am aware of the Harnack's Inequality for linear elliptic equations.

My questions are:

(a) Is there a version of Harnack's Inequality for nonlinear elliptic equations, say, of the form $$Lu = |u|^pu ?$$
where $L$ is elliptic?

(b) How about the same question (I am actually more interested in this) when $L$ is hypoelliptic?

(c) Suppose I have a non-negative solution to the equation $Lu = |u|^pu $, with $L$ being elliptic/hypoelliptic. I want to show that the solution is actually positive. What other generic method is there to proceed other than Harnack's Inequality? I realise this last question is kind of vague, but I hope the intent behind the question is clear.

Comment: I would be quite surprised if (b) were true, since there are hypoelliptic operators whose Green's functions achieve negative values (see, for example, Garabedian's simple example for the bi-Laplacian on a sufficiently eccentric ellipse, in his text on PDEs).

You may want to repeat this question over at Mathoverflow, since I suspect parts of it are definitely at the research level.